# Crypting part of a stream to another stream

Tags: c#, cryptography

My application requires the need to crypt parts of a stream to other streams, as some files have some parts encrypted with one key and others with other keys. To support this, I tried to make  a method that crypts a part of a stream using an `ICryptoTransform` (yes, crypt, since `ICryptoTransform`s can be decryptors or encryptors) with a given offset and size, and it should be buffered.

This was my idea:

- Open a buffer stream, for data chunks
- Open a `CryptoStream`, and pass the buffer stream into it

Read and hopefully crypt it like this:

- Read a chunk (the size of `bufferSize`) from the stream
- Write that chunk into the crypto stream (which should write it to the
  buffer stream)
- Call `.Flush()` on that, to make sure the data
  has been crypted
- Write the contents of the buffer stream to the output stream
- Seek the buffer stream back to the beginning, so that a new chunk can be written and crypted in it
- Repeat until `offset + size` has been reached on the input stream.

This is my current code:

```cs
public static void CryptStreamPartBuffered(Stream input, Stream output, ICryptoTransform transform, long offset, long size, int bufferSize = 4000000)
{
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream()) //opening a memory stream, which will be the "buffer" for the crypted chunks
    {
        using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, transform, CryptoStreamMode.Write)) //opening a cryptostream on the "buffer" stream, to crypt it's contents
        {
            input.Seek(offset, SeekOrigin.Begin); //seeking input stream to given start offset

            byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

            while (input.Position < offset + size)
            {
                int remaining = bufferSize, bytesRead;

                while (remaining > 0 && (bytesRead = input.Read(buffer, 0, Math.Min(remaining, bufferSize))) > 0)
                {
                    remaining -= bytesRead;

                    cs.Write(buffer); //writing current chunk of data to crypto stream
                    cs.Flush(); //making sure that the crypto stream has done its work on the current chunk (although I'm not really sure whether this is the right thing to do)

                    output.Write(ms.ToArray()); //writing the (hopefully) crypted data to the output stream
                    ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin); //re-seeking the chunk stream to it's beginning, so that when the next chunk gets crypted, it can be written there
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This straight-up doesn't work for files smaller than the default buffer size. While I do know that this can be fixed by just setting a smaller buffer size manually when calling the method, but having the support would be great.

However, this doesn't seem to do its job very well. I seem to get garbled data and I feel like I'm doing something wrong here, probably some very obvious mistake I just can't figure out.

Comment: I don't get it. Why use a MemoryStream at all? Why just wrap the CryptoStream around `input`? Also, you're writing the `entire` buffer out every time when only the first `bytesRead` bytes of the buffer contain valid data.

Comment: I do not want to close the input stream doing this. When the `CryptoStream` gets disposed, the input stream would get disposed as well, which isn't what I want to do.

You have a valid point there for the buffer part though.

Comment: Correct usage of CryptoStreams **requires** that `FlushFinalBlock()` be called at *the end*. This can be done explicitly, or it can be done as in your case as part of the `Dispose()` call which happens implicitly when the `using` statement block is exited. However, when your using block is exited, the cipher output generated from `FlushFinalBlock()`  is discarded. This will result in data corruption since you're throwing away data. You've provided an explanation for what you're trying to do, but I'm afraid I didn't quite understand it. Perhaps if you explain why I might understand better.

Comment: Let's say I've got a file with 2 chunks, each encrypted with different keys. I want to decrypt both into separate files. This would be done by running the above method twice. Since I would like to be able to use the input stream normally afterward, I'm using a "buffer memory stream" as the backing of the CryptoStream, then write the buffered data (to avoid using tons of RAM) into the CryptoStream (which I thought would work) and repeat that until it reaches offset+size. I think it seems better to copy the chunk into the output stream, and then perform cryptography on the output stream instead.